# Need to check file in the AjaxFileUpload are already uploaded or not

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How can I validate that the file selected in **AjaxFileUpload** is already uploaded or are Pending

For eg:

[image]

**I want to validate for those file which are still pending to be uploaded.**
Here is my .aspx page code

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server"
        Width="400px" OnUploadComplete="OnUploadComplete" Mode="Auto" />       
</form>
```

.aspx.cs code is

```
 protected void OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + fileName));
    }
```

Suppose I had already uploaded 2 files and then after I add a new file to get upload but How can I validate that 2 files are uploaded and the new placed file is not uploaded.
I need to validate this from java script

**I need to validate this on any button onclientclick event.**

**Resolved with below javascript**

```
function validateImageUploaded() {
if ($(".ajax__fileupload_fileItemInfo").length > 0) {
    if ($("div.ajax__fileupload_fileItemInfo").children('div').hasClass("pendingState"))
    {
        alert("found");
        return false;
    }
}
else {
    alert('select your file');
    return false;
}}
```

Comment: You forgot to include your code

Comment: @AlonEitan now added the code please remove it from on hold

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using **.children** and **.hasClass**

```
$("div.ajax__fileupload_fileItemInfo").children('div').hasClass("pendingState")
```